# Channels current state is unavailable in Laravel WebSockets on production(Ubuntu 20.04.4)

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-websockets

I am trying to setup websockets on larvel-9.0 project. when I try to open /laravel-websockets I am getting the following error in console.
project is setup on Ubuntu 20.04.4.

> pusher.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://dev.mydomain.in:6001/app/mywebsocketkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false'
> failed:

I am getting an success response when I am trying to connect this through postman with url

> wss://dev.mydomain.in:6001/app/mywebsocketkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.3.1&flash=false

and i am getting following response in postman.

```
{
    "event": "pusher:connection_established",
    "data": "{\"socket_id\":\"371175048.259495464\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"
}
```

I have followed [Websockets documentation](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/installation).

Here are the ***broadcast.php*** configuration

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => 'dev.mydomain.in',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'https',
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

***Websockets.php***

```
'apps' => [
        [
            'host' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_HOST', "127.0.0.1"),
            'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'encrypted' => true
        ],
    ],
```

***bootstrap.js***

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

 window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: true,
    disableStats: true,    
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

***.env***

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1234
PUSHER_APP_KEY=mywebsocketkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=hjhasjdhajsh
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_HOST="dev.mydomain.in"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT=6001
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="/usr/dev/ssl-fullchain.pem"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="/usr/dev/ssl.key"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE=null
```

Comment: are you trying to open dashboard?]

Comment: If deployed to production and uses SSL, add In bootstrap.js, try adding wssPort: 6001,

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth Yes I opened dashboard, while I click on connect ia getting **Channels current state is unavailable** , I tried with even wssPort: 6001, wssHost:window.location.hostname but getting same error.

Comment: You cannot open dashboard if your app_env is not local

Comment: Aside from that, can you check if your port is open? In centos `sudo netstat -tpunl | grep 6001`

Comment: app_env is set to local and port 6001 is open. I can access it with postman.

Comment: is this ec2 instance?

Comment: its a linode instance with ubuntu 20.04.4 with PHP-FPM 8.1.12.

Comment: I am not sure if this will solve your problem. In my laravel 8, I use in my composer
`"beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.13",`
`"pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",`

and npm
`"laravel-echo": "^1.14.0",`
`"pusher-js": "^7.4.0",`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249686/discussion-between-asimdev-and-mr-kenneth).

Comment: I think i having the same error now. It was working before until I installed SSL . 
Now I get "Channels current state is unavailable"

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the same value for `PUSHER_APP_ID`, `PUSHER_APP_KEY` and
`PUSHER_APP_SECRET` in `.env` file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33459775)